# Change the background tint with kotliin

Tags: android, kotlin, background-color

I create an Android App with Kotlin, I have the following problem : 
In one of my UI, I create a constraint layout which has the following :

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/cart"
    android:background="@drawable/circle_vs_shape"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:tint="@color/whiteFour"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/add_cart" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I want to change the background tint of this constraint layout when I click on.In the setonclickListener of this constraint I add the following code but it didn't change

```
 constraint.backgroundTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#FF8800"))
```

How can I correct my code, to change the backgound tint color?

Comment: Is circle_vs_shape is a vector asset?

Comment: No, It just a black cercle in a drawable ressource file xml

Comment: I edited my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally there are several ways to fix this:

```
    ConstraintLayout someLayout=(ConstraintLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.someLayout);
    someLayout.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#ff8800"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

If it's an aregular asset (the background is an image and not vector) you could create a color selector in the `color` folder.

You could also use two Images which will have a different image and a different tint color instead of a container and an imageview.

**Edit**

place it in the color folder

**email_phone_color_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@color/sms_phone_disabled"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/sms_phone_disabled"/>
    <item android:color="@color/sms_phone_enabled"/>
</selector>
```

And use it

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cart"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@color/email_phone_color_selector"
    app:tint="@color/colorAccent">
```